# VB6 Picturebox.Line tuple arguments

Tags: vb6, drawing, picturebox

I have just come across a surprising feature of VB6.

The `PictureBox` control has a method `Line`:

> Sub Line(Flags As Integer, X1 As Single, Y1 As Single, X2 As Single, Y2 As Single, Color As Long)

But it is usually called like this:

```
Picture1.Line (lastX, lastY)-(X, Y), vbBlue
```

I never knew this "auto-unbox" feature. And the `flags` parameter seems to be skipped, but is not `Optional`.

What sorcery is this? Is this a special feature of this control or of the language? Can other controls use this feature?

Comment: It gets a lot more interesting when you include STEP and the optional B or F argument.  B and F are not keywords or variables.  Nothing to do with the method call syntax, the compiler itself recognizes "LINE" and knows it is special.  Goes way, way back to early interpreters.  Killed off at VB.NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a syntax inherited from QBASIC where most graphics functions used `(x, y)` to represent screen coordinates, E.g. `LINE ([X], [Y]) - ([X], [Y]), [Colour]`.

The syntax is unique within the language and cannot be represented as a COM call, the object inspector shows what the call is presumably translated to by the compiler.

They likely left it simply for portability/compatibility reasons, like so much else in Visual Basic.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your Line method definition is not correct for the picturebox control.  You probably copy-pasted your definition from the object browser?  I've never figured out why the object browser is apparently wrong on this point. (or at least I've never used that syntax)

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa230480(v=vs.60).aspx for the details on the Line method for the picturebox control.  This describes your 'sorcery' call syntax :).

Comment: True, that's what I did. Thanks for the link.